# Ordering with id for a distinct column

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a social networking site having private messaging features. When one user sends a private message, data will be inserted into the table called 'pm' in the following format with default value read=0.

```
_________________________________
| id | sender  | receiver | text | time | read |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1  |   A      |    B     |  abc |  x   |   0   |
| 2  |   B      |    A     |  abc |  y   |   1   |
| 3  |   A     |    C     |  abc |  z   |   0   |
| 4  |   C     |    B     |  abc |  a   |   1    |
| 5  |   B     |    A     |  abc |  b   |   0   |
| 6  |   A     |    D     |  abc |  c   |   0   |
| 7  |   D     |    A     |  abc |  d   |   1   |
| 8  |   A     |    B     |  abc |  e   |   0   |
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
```

I have used the following bit of mysql code to list the user who has done private message with the user A.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sender from pm where receiver='A'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT receiver from pm where sender='A'
```

This code works fine but I actually want to order the data with id in descending order so that latest sender will be shown in the top of the list and so on.

I used     ORDER by id desc    but returns     UNKNOWN COLUMN id    .

Note: column 'id' is a primary key.

Hope anyone will solve this issue.

Regards.

Comment: Use created_at, updated_at timestamps

Comment: Are user names for both sender and receiver unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..

```
SELECT distinct sender from ((SELECT DISTINCT pm.id,pm.sender from pm where receiver='A')
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT pm.id,pm.receiver from pm where sender='A')
order by id desc) as abc
```

Comment: This is what I actually want. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

```
select sender,receiver from ((SELECT DISTINCT pm.id,pm.sender from pm where receiver='A'
     UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT pm.id,pm.receiver from pm where sender='A')) as abc ORDER BY pm.id;
```

try this...

Comment: I am sorry sir but it returned -  Error : Unknown column 'sender' in 'field list'

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for upvoting..sorry

Answer (score 0):

If User names for both sender and receiver are unique then you could do this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) as UserId, UserName FROM
(
 SELECT DISTINCT sender as UserName from pm where receiver='A'
 UNION
 SELECT DISTINCT receiver as UserName from pm where sender='A'
) tbl
INNER JOIN pm t1
ON tbl.UserName = t1.Sender
INNER JOIN pm t2 
ON tlb.UserName = t2.Receiver
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: I tried this code but returned Error : Column 'id in field list is ambiguous